# Shell script for files matching a pattern and count occurence per directory

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have the following problem: I want to count migration files per directory.

My structure always looks like this:

```
/some/path/app1/migrations/0001_hello_world.py  
/some/path/app2/migrations/0001_foo.py  
/some/path/app2/migrations/0002_bar.py
```

What I need is a shell script, in the best case a one-liner to get the following result:

```
app1: 1
app2: 2
```

So I get the numbers of files per app directory.

I got as far as getting my list of files:

```
git diff --color --name-only --diff-filter=A origin/develop my-branch | grep "\/migrations\/[0-9]"
```

**I can count all of those matches with `wc -l` but I cannot count per directory.**

Unfortunately even with google and stack, I'm stuck.

Any ideas on that topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
git diff --color --name-only --diff-filter=A origin/develop my-branch \
    | grep '/migrations/[0-9]' \
    | cut -d/ -f4 \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c
```

adapt the field number of `cut` (here: `4`) as necessary.

Output:

```
  2 app1
  1 app2
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
$ for folder in *; do echo "$folder: "; \
    find ./$folder -type f | wc -l; done | grep -A 1 "some/path/"`
```

Comment: how would i combine it with my `git diff`?

Comment: Could you try piping it before the find? Like this: `for folder in *; do echo "$folder: "; git diff --color --name-only --diff-filter=A origin/develop my-branch | find ./$folder -type f | wc -l; done | grep -A 1 "dir"`

Comment: and what would `"dir"` be? sorry, not so familiar with shell scripting :(